# How can I tell many unicorn workers are running on a heroku dyno right now?

Tags: heroku, unicorn

I know that you can look in config/unicorn.rb (or the equivalent) and see what those settings are, but I'm wondering specifically how I can tell, right now, how many unicorn workers are running on a given dyno.

I tried to ps aux after running 'heroku run bash' but that didn't give me the actual processes  the dyno was running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run:

```
$ heroku run bash
$ unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb &
$ ps euf
```

you should get something similar to this:

```
USER   PID %CPU %MEM VSZ    RSS    TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
u16236 2   0.0  0.0  19444  2024   ?   S    20:55 0:00 bash GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=XXX HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL=postgres://XXX:
u16236 3   19.4 0.3  288716 131568 ?   Sl   20:55 0:04  \_ unicorn master -c config/unicorn.rb -l0.0.0.0:8080 GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=XXX
u16236 5   31.0 0.3  305844 129636 ?   Sl   20:55 0:04  |   \_ sidekiq 3.2.5 app [0 of 2 busy] GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_
u16236 7   0.0  0.3  288716 124724 ?   Sl   20:55 0:00  |   \_ unicorn worker[0] -c config/unicorn.rb -l0.0.0.0:8080 GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=XXX
u16236 10  0.0  0.3  288716 124728 ?   Sl   20:55 0:00  |   \_ unicorn worker[1] -c config/unicorn.rb -l0.0.0.0:8080 GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=XXX
u16236 13  0.0  0.3  288716 124728 ?   Sl   20:55 0:00  |   \_ unicorn worker[2] -c config/unicorn.rb -l0.0.0.0:8080 GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=XXX
u16236 30  0.0  0.0  15328  1104   ?   R+   20:55 0:00  \_ ps euf GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=XXX DEVISE_PEPPER=XXX
```

You can see that processes 7, 10, & 13 are my 3 Unicorn workers that are each consuming 30% of total memory.

Comment: Wow, had no idea you could run a bash shell on a heroku machine. That's pretty great.

Comment: Neither did I until I started looking for what my Unicorn workers were doing.

Comment: I think in this case it is using .3% and not 30% of the memory. 

This could be because you are not actually pointing any traffic to the node running unicorn.